# kdeinit5 crashes twice on boot, but my laptop boots fine and everything appears to work

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kde, kubuntu, kde-plasma-5

When I turn on my linux laptop, I am informed that kdeinit5 has crashed. This appears to have no impact, I can use Firefox normally and the kde plasma widgets and toolbar appear as they usually do. I'm including two sets of crash information from two boots.

## Boot 1

I turned on my computer, and was informed twice that kdeinit5 had crashed, and the the Baloo File Indexing Daemon had crashed.

### First window

(kdeinit5, pid 6374)

```
The crash information could not be generated
```

### Second window

(kdeinit 5, pid 6428)

```
Application: kdeinit5 (kdeinit5), signal: Segmentation fault
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
[Current thread is 1 (Thread 0x7f211ae22780 (LWP 6428))]

Thread 3 (Thread 0x7f210ffff700 (LWP 6456)):
#0  0x00007f211e46f729 in __GI___poll (fds=0x7f2108004e30, nfds=1, timeout=-1) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/poll.c:29
#1  0x00007f211cae7cb6 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#2  0x00007f211cae7ddc in g_main_context_iteration () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#3  0x00007f211e80f063 in QEventDispatcherGlib::processEvents(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#4  0x00007f211e7ba5bb in QEventLoop::exec(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#5  0x00007f211e6052c6 in QThread::exec() () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#6  0x00007f211a337565 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5DBus.so.5
#7  0x00007f211e606612 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#8  0x00007f211d44a182 in start_thread (arg=<optimized out>) at pthread_create.c:486
#9  0x00007f211e47bb1f in clone () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/clone.S:95

Thread 2 (Thread 0x7f2118404700 (LWP 6430)):
#0  0x00007f211e46f729 in __GI___poll (fds=0x7f2118403d28, nfds=1, timeout=-1) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/poll.c:29
#1  0x00007f211f079917 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1
#2  0x00007f211f07b53a in xcb_wait_for_event () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1
#3  0x00007f2118f9d6a8 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5XcbQpa.so.5
#4  0x00007f211e606612 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#5  0x00007f211d44a182 in start_thread (arg=<optimized out>) at pthread_create.c:486
#6  0x00007f211e47bb1f in clone () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/clone.S:95

Thread 1 (Thread 0x7f211ae22780 (LWP 6428)):
[KCrash Handler]
#6  __memmove_avx_unaligned_erms () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/memmove-vec-unaligned-erms.S:262
#7  0x00007f211f252938 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/kf5/kio/thumbnail.so
#8  0x00007f211a79bf16 in KIO::SlaveBase::dispatch(int, QByteArray const&) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libKF5KIOCore.so.5
#9  0x00007f211a79c5d6 in KIO::SlaveBase::dispatchLoop() () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libKF5KIOCore.so.5
#10 0x00007f211f24f0bc in kdemain () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/kf5/kio/thumbnail.so
#11 0x0000557613efce1c in ?? ()
#12 0x0000557613efdeea in ?? ()
#13 0x0000557613efe8fb in ?? ()
#14 0x0000557613ef9645 in ?? ()
#15 0x00007f211e384b6b in __libc_start_main (main=0x557613ef8c70, argc=5, argv=0x7ffda66d4c78, init=<optimized out>, fini=<optimized out>, rtld_fini=<optimized out>, stack_end=0x7ffda66d4c68) at ../csu/libc-start.c:308
#16 0x0000557613efa2ca in ?? ()
[Inferior 1 (process 6428) detached]
```

### Third window

(Baloo File Indexing Daemon, pid 4085)

```
Application: Baloo File Indexing Daemon (baloo_file), signal: Segmentation fault
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
[Current thread is 1 (Thread 0x7f5205f98080 (LWP 4085))]

Thread 2 (Thread 0x7f5205a25700 (LWP 4100)):
#0  0x00007f5209d5e729 in __GI___poll (fds=0x7f5200005260, nfds=1, timeout=-1) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/poll.c:29
#1  0x00007f5208683cb6 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#2  0x00007f5208683ddc in g_main_context_iteration () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#3  0x00007f520a42d063 in QEventDispatcherGlib::processEvents(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#4  0x00007f520a3d85bb in QEventLoop::exec(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#5  0x00007f520a2232c6 in QThread::exec() () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#6  0x00007f520a7d3565 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5DBus.so.5
#7  0x00007f520a224612 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#8  0x00007f5208d4a182 in start_thread (arg=<optimized out>) at pthread_create.c:486
#9  0x00007f5209d6ab1f in clone () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/clone.S:95

Thread 1 (Thread 0x7f5205f98080 (LWP 4085)):
[KCrash Handler]
#6  0x00005611a21df34a in ?? ()
#7  0x00005611a21e0379 in ?? ()
#8  0x00005611a21de1eb in ?? ()
#9  0x00007f520a403ca2 in QObject::event(QEvent*) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#10 0x00007f520a3d98c6 in QCoreApplication::notifyInternal2(QObject*, QEvent*) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#11 0x00007f520a3dc927 in QCoreApplicationPrivate::sendPostedEvents(QObject*, int, QThreadData*) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#12 0x00007f520a42da43 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#13 0x00007f5208683aae in g_main_context_dispatch () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#14 0x00007f5208683d48 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#15 0x00007f5208683ddc in g_main_context_iteration () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#16 0x00007f520a42d047 in QEventDispatcherGlib::processEvents(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#17 0x00007f520a3d85bb in QEventLoop::exec(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#18 0x00007f520a3e05e2 in QCoreApplication::exec() () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#19 0x00005611a21b7997 in ?? ()
#20 0x00007f5209c73b6b in __libc_start_main (main=0x5611a21b7610, argc=1, argv=0x7ffcc42605c8, init=<optimized out>, fini=<optimized out>, rtld_fini=<optimized out>, stack_end=0x7ffcc42605b8) at ../csu/libc-start.c:308
#21 0x00005611a21b7b3a in ?? ()
[Inferior 1 (process 4085) detached]
```

## Boot 2

After opening a text editor to record the above information, I restarted my laptop. This time, the Baloo File Indexing Daemon didn't crash.

### First window

(kdeinit5, pid 7233)

```
Application: kdeinit5 (kdeinit5), signal: Segmentation fault
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
[Current thread is 1 (Thread 0x7fe8ad81a780 (LWP 7233))]

Thread 3 (Thread 0x7fe8a8839700 (LWP 7299)):
#0  __GI___libc_read (nbytes=16, buf=0x7fe8a8838bd0, fd=13) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/read.c:26
#1  __GI___libc_read (fd=13, buf=0x7fe8a8838bd0, nbytes=16) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/read.c:24
#2  0x00007fe8af526550 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#3  0x00007fe8af4df78f in g_main_context_check () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#4  0x00007fe8af4dfc60 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#5  0x00007fe8af4dfddc in g_main_context_iteration () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#6  0x00007fe8b1207063 in QEventDispatcherGlib::processEvents(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#7  0x00007fe8b11b25bb in QEventLoop::exec(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#8  0x00007fe8b0ffd2c6 in QThread::exec() () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#9  0x00007fe8acd2f565 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5DBus.so.5
#10 0x00007fe8b0ffe612 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#11 0x00007fe8afe42182 in start_thread (arg=<optimized out>) at pthread_create.c:486
#12 0x00007fe8b0e73b1f in clone () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/clone.S:95

Thread 2 (Thread 0x7fe8aadfc700 (LWP 7243)):
#0  0x00007fe8b0e67729 in __GI___poll (fds=0x7fe8aadfbd28, nfds=1, timeout=-1) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/poll.c:29
#1  0x00007fe8b1a71917 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1
#2  0x00007fe8b1a7353a in xcb_wait_for_event () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1
#3  0x00007fe8ab9956a8 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5XcbQpa.so.5
#4  0x00007fe8b0ffe612 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#5  0x00007fe8afe42182 in start_thread (arg=<optimized out>) at pthread_create.c:486
#6  0x00007fe8b0e73b1f in clone () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/clone.S:95

Thread 1 (Thread 0x7fe8ad81a780 (LWP 7233)):
[KCrash Handler]
#6  __memmove_avx_unaligned_erms () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/memmove-vec-unaligned-erms.S:262
#7  0x00007fe8b1c4a938 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/kf5/kio/thumbnail.so
#8  0x00007fe8ad193f16 in KIO::SlaveBase::dispatch(int, QByteArray const&) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libKF5KIOCore.so.5
#9  0x00007fe8ad1945d6 in KIO::SlaveBase::dispatchLoop() () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libKF5KIOCore.so.5
#10 0x00007fe8b1c470bc in kdemain () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/kf5/kio/thumbnail.so
#11 0x000055c6509d9e1c in ?? ()
#12 0x000055c6509daeea in ?? ()
#13 0x000055c6509db8fb in ?? ()
#14 0x000055c6509d6645 in ?? ()
#15 0x00007fe8b0d7cb6b in __libc_start_main (main=0x55c6509d5c70, argc=5, argv=0x7fff80759f28, init=<optimized out>, fini=<optimized out>, rtld_fini=<optimized out>, stack_end=0x7fff80759f18) at ../csu/libc-start.c:308
#16 0x000055c6509d72ca in ?? ()
[Inferior 1 (process 7233) detached]
```

### Second window

(kdeinit5, pid 7090)

```
Application: kdeinit5 (kdeinit5), signal: Segmentation fault
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
[Current thread is 1 (Thread 0x7fe8ad81a780 (LWP 7090))]

Thread 3 (Thread 0x7fe8a8839700 (LWP 7209)):
#0  0x00007fe8b0e67729 in __GI___poll (fds=0x7fe89c004e30, nfds=1, timeout=-1) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/poll.c:29
#1  0x00007fe8af4dfcb6 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#2  0x00007fe8af4dfddc in g_main_context_iteration () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#3  0x00007fe8b1207063 in QEventDispatcherGlib::processEvents(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#4  0x00007fe8b11b25bb in QEventLoop::exec(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#5  0x00007fe8b0ffd2c6 in QThread::exec() () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#6  0x00007fe8acd2f565 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5DBus.so.5
#7  0x00007fe8b0ffe612 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#8  0x00007fe8afe42182 in start_thread (arg=<optimized out>) at pthread_create.c:486
#9  0x00007fe8b0e73b1f in clone () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/clone.S:95

Thread 2 (Thread 0x7fe8aadfc700 (LWP 7104)):
#0  0x00007fe8b0e67729 in __GI___poll (fds=0x7fe8aadfbd28, nfds=1, timeout=-1) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/poll.c:29
#1  0x00007fe8b1a71917 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1
#2  0x00007fe8b1a7353a in xcb_wait_for_event () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1
#3  0x00007fe8ab9956a8 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5XcbQpa.so.5
#4  0x00007fe8b0ffe612 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#5  0x00007fe8afe42182 in start_thread (arg=<optimized out>) at pthread_create.c:486
#6  0x00007fe8b0e73b1f in clone () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/clone.S:95

Thread 1 (Thread 0x7fe8ad81a780 (LWP 7090)):
[KCrash Handler]
#6  __memmove_avx_unaligned_erms () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/memmove-vec-unaligned-erms.S:262
#7  0x00007fe8b1c4a938 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/kf5/kio/thumbnail.so
#8  0x00007fe8ad193f16 in KIO::SlaveBase::dispatch(int, QByteArray const&) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libKF5KIOCore.so.5
#9  0x00007fe8ad1945d6 in KIO::SlaveBase::dispatchLoop() () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libKF5KIOCore.so.5
#10 0x00007fe8b1c470bc in kdemain () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/kf5/kio/thumbnail.so
#11 0x000055c6509d9e1c in ?? ()
#12 0x000055c6509daeea in ?? ()
#13 0x000055c6509db8fb in ?? ()
#14 0x000055c6509d6645 in ?? ()
#15 0x00007fe8b0d7cb6b in __libc_start_main (main=0x55c6509d5c70, argc=5, argv=0x7fff80759f28, init=<optimized out>, fini=<optimized out>, rtld_fini=<optimized out>, stack_end=0x7fff80759f18) at ../csu/libc-start.c:308
#16 0x000055c6509d72ca in ?? ()
[Inferior 1 (process 7090) detached]
```

## System Information

```
> hostnamectl
...
Operating System: Ubuntu 19.04
          Kernel: Linux 5.0.10-surface-linux-surface
    Architecture: x86-64
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR**: Indexing Plasma Vaults causes problems. Exclude the folders the vaults mount into from File Search.

---

I posted the question on reddit, at which point the user [skugler](https://www.reddit.com/user/skugler/) replied

> Looks like a kio thumbnail process and a Baloo proceeds is crashing, that likely means that a thumbail hasn't been created and a file not indexed. These things aren't fatal, you may not even notice them at all [in] your usage, or your indexer may be missing the contents of a file and some thumbail couldn't be generated. ([Source](https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/comments/bsdd3m/kdeinit5_crashes_twice_on_boot_but_my_laptop/eon7htc?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x))

I realized that the problem started at the same time I created a [Plasma Vault](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/06/plasma-vault-create-encrypted-folder-linux). Vaults are encrypted folders that are stored in a hidden location and when unlocked mount into a pre-existing empty folder. In my case, I had a vault called "Secrets" that mounted into the empty folder "~/Secrets".

Both the indexing error and the thumbnail generation error related somehow to attempts to index the disappearing contents of the vault folder. I stopped receiving error messages after I added the directory the vault mounts into to the list of directories not indexed by File Search in the File Search pane of System Settings (shown in the image below).

[Link to an image of the File Search pane of System Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ymsle.png)
(I can't post images)